# Using Steam's Proton to run Roblox

Tags: steam, emulation

My 21.10 machine has [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/linux) installed, and steam comes with [Proton emulator](https://www.protondb.com/). Valve calls this "Steam Play."

With this, I can play windows-games I get from steam on Ubuntu, just fine. Even if the publisher did not publish a linux binary.

My kids are into [Roblox](https://roblox.com), and would like to play that under Ubuntu.

But Roblox has no Linux client. And Roblox is not available from steam.

Is there a way to leverage the Proton emulator that comes w steam, to run Roblox?

Alternatively, should I install a separate emulator for it? if I do so, will it clash with Proton that is already present on the system for Steam?

[image]

Comment: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-roblox-game-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/ <- the instructions include installing Wine from the WineHQ repository. It probably works as well with the older version available in the official Ubuntu repositories. Steam's Proton is based on Wine but AFAIK it can't be used for software not distributed by Steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to use Steam's Proton for running Roblox. However, Proton is, I believe, a fork of Wine, which you theoretically can use to run Roblox. From my little experience with Wine, it's quite complicated to use and has some quirks and end up not being a great user experience, but it's basically the only option.

Here is a guide I found on running Roblox on Linux using Wine: [Using Roblox on Linux](https://roblox.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorial:Using_Roblox_on_Linux)

Comment: wine from Ubuntu21.10 seems to run Roblox Studio just fine! Still need to try the game itself. I got to studio by running wine on RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe from the roblox website.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to. Click the Add Game and then make sure to force it to use proton for that "game". I've done this for applications because they run better on Proton than Wine

Answer (score 0):

Wine is no longer supported by Roblox at this time. This change occurred in the last couple months.

https://www.gamingonlinux.com/2023/04/roblox-intentionally-blocking-linux-with-wine-in-their-new-update/